# jQuery dialog not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( "#addLocation" ).dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        height: 700,
        width: 550,
        buttons: {
            "Add Location": function() {
                document.forms["mapform"].submit();
            },
            Cancel: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        },
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function showLocationDialog() {
    $("#addLocation").dialog("open");
}
</script>

<div id="addLocation" style="display:none;">
<form action="" method="post" name="mapform">
<input type="text" name="name" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
</div>

<button onclick="javascript:showLocationDialog();">Add an address</button>
```

The button does not open the dialog and I cannot understand why.. can anyone assist?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wait for the DOM to be ready.

Stick your `.dialog()` code in a `$(document).ready()` or `$()` block

Answer (score 1):

1 - Put the `.dialog()` initialization into a [`$(document).ready() { ... });`](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aIntroducing_%24%28document%29.ready%28%29).

2 - Remove the extra comma from after the buttons value:

```
buttons: {
            "Add Location": function() {
                document.forms["mapform"].submit();
            },
            Cancel: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        }, <-- remove this, causes IE to spontaneously combust
```

Answer (score 0):

another thing to try...

remove the `display:none` css from the addLocation div..the dialog will take care of hiding everything once its initialized on document.ready

Comment: That's not such a good idea; the inline css hides the form *before* the dom is ready - this has two advantages, firstly the user doesn't see something and then see it disappear, which is confusing, and the browser doesn't waste resources rendering while loading and then rerendering when the dom is ready and dialog() hides it all.